# Capitalize First Letter of each word in a string (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want output like this:

```
var String1 = "stack over flow" 
var desiredOutPut = "Stack Over Flow"
```

Also, I want this output in TextField event named "textFieldDidChange" so it must be efficient as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

```
var desiredOutPut = String1.capitalized
```